# SendMessage works with WM_CHAR but not with WM_KEYDOWN

Tags: c, windows, keyboard-events, keydown, sendmessage

I would like to be able to simulate arrow key presses on Windows 10 using C. Moreover, I would like to avoid having to have the window I send these arrow key presses to active at all times, hence my attempts avoid the use of `SendInput()` and `keybd_event()`. I believe that this leaves me with few other options than using sending the message `WM_KEYDOWN` with `SendMessage()`.

As a first test with using the `WM_KEYDOWN` message, though, I am trying to send the keypress `A` to notepad, just so that I can see what's going on. This lead to with the following two lines of code:

```
SendMessage(child_window, WM_CHAR, (WPARAM)0x41, (LPARAM)0);
SendMessage(child_window, WM_KEYDOWN, (WPARAM)0x41, (LPARAM)0);
```

The first one works: it types the letter `A` in notepad. The second one does not, though, and I'm having trouble figuring out why. Any suggestions?

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
  HWND window = FindWindow("Notepad", NULL);
  if (window == NULL)
  {
    printf("Could not find the window.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  HWND child_window = FindWindowEx(window, NULL, "Edit", NULL);
  if (child_window == NULL)
  {
    printf("Child window could not be found.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  SendMessage(child_window, WM_CHAR, (WPARAM)0x41, (LPARAM)0);
  SendMessage(child_window, WM_KEYDOWN, (WPARAM)0x41, (LPARAM)0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wasn't that WM_KEYDOWN uses key code? Furthermore, a WM_KEYDOWN without WM_KEYUP didn't reflect a complete key click cycle.

Comment: I tried adding WM_KEYUP as well, but unfortunately with no success. I don't quite follow what you mean by "wasn't that WM_KEYDOWN uses key code?"

Comment: For what reason are you avoiding `SendInput`? And why not simply copy/paste the text?

Comment: You need to use `PostMessage` to queue a message to the thread that owns the window. The thread's message loop gets a message from the queue via `GetMessage` and translates `WM_KEYDOWN` to `WM_CHAR` via `TranslateMessage`. OTOH, messages sent via `SendMessage` are flagged for immediate dispatch to the window procedure -- because the sender is waiting for a reply. They aren't returned by `GetMessage` and thus a key-down message that's sent instead of posted won't get translated to a character message.

Comment: Please read [About Messages and Message Queues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927). It's fundamental to Windows programming.

Answer (score -1):

Ah, this is probably just because the notepad procedure only appends letters to its edit window when it encounters a `WM_CHAR` event, which is not that weird after all. The cursor does move when using the `WM_KEYDOWN` event in conjunction with the arrow virtual key codes.